# Itos formula on a transformation of bessel Processes

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and $z,\kappa>0$. Let $X_t(z)$ be a solution to the SDE

$$dX_t(z)=dW_t+2/(\kappa X_t(z))dt.\quad X_0(z)=z.$$

The solution is well-defined on $t<\tau(z)$ where $\tau(z)$ is a stopping time . Moreover, $X_t(z)\rightarrow 0$ for $t\uparrow\tau$. Hence $X_t(z):=0$ for $t\geq \tau$ makes $X(z)$ a continuous semimartingale. Consider now $y>x>0$. Then $P(\tau(x)\leq\tau(y))=1$, and almost surely $X_t(x)<X_t(y)$ for all $t<\tau$.  Define also

$$\vartheta_t=\frac{X_t(y)-X_t(x)}{X_t(y)}.$$

The notes that i am reading applies Itos formula with $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{y}$ to conclude that

$$\vartheta_t-\vartheta_0=\int_0^t (\frac{\vartheta_s}{X_s(y)})^2(-\frac{2/k}{1-\vartheta_s}+\frac{1-1/\kappa}{\vartheta_s})ds-\int_0^t \frac{\vartheta_s}{X_s(y)}dW_s,\quad t<\tau.$$

**My question is how Itos formula can be applied, since $f$ is not $C_2$ on the line $y=0$. Moreover, is the process a semimartingale?**

I can't see how this is done. I have tried approximating by using stopping times for when $X_t(x)$ hits small r, but then i don't know how to remove them for the integral again.

Comment: Since $X_t(y) > 0$ for $t < \tau$, it looks like you only need $f(x, y)$ to be $C^2$ for $y > 0$.

Comment: Why is that? I have only seen Itos formula defined on $[0,\infty)$ processes for cadlag semimartingales. If i define say $X_t(y)=0$ for $t\geq \tau$ then how do i know that the process is cadlag?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that SLE$_{\kappa}$ covers open sets in zero time for $4 <\kappa<8$ but not for $\kappa\geq 8$? If so, see Proposition 1.21 in Lawler's book on conformally invariant plane processes.

Comment: You only need $f$ to be $C^2$ on the set $y>0$, since the stated formula is only valid for $t<\tau$. Moreover, Ito's formula is a justification within itself that a $C^2$ function of semimartingales is itself a semimartingale, no?

Comment: Im trying to prove a similar statement for $SLE_k$ yes.
I still don't understand why that is true. Maybe we are not talking about the same version of Itos Formula.

The version i know is similar to theorem 1 here: 
https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/
It requires that $X$ is a process defined at all times $t\in [0,\infty)$, and that $X_{t-}$ is contained in $U={y>0}$.

Comment: $X$ as in the blogs "X" and therefore corresponding to my $\vartheta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that you can't directly apply Ito's formula as it is stated in most textbooks, it is nonetheless true that Ito's Formula is valid in this case when $t<\tau$. Indeed we will prove a more general fact.

Suppose $U \subset \Bbb R^d$ is an open set, and $f: U \to \Bbb R$ is a $C^2$ function. Suppose $X=(X^1,...,X^d)$ is a continuous semimartingale with $X_0\in U$ a.s., and let $\tau_U$ denote the first exit time of $X$ from $U$.

**Claim:** Ito's formula for $f(X_t)$ holds whenever $t< \tau_U$.

**Proof:** For $n \in \Bbb N$, let $\tau_U^{(n)}$ denote the first time $t$ such that $dist(X_t, U^c)<\frac{1}{n}$. Then the stopped process $X^{\tau^{(n)}_U}$ is a semimartingale taking values in $U$ for all time, hence Ito's formula for $f(X^{\tau_U^{(n)}})$ is valid in the usual sense of the theorem (that you cited in your comment). This implies that for all $n$ the events $E_n:=\{ $Ito's formula for $f(X_t)$ holds when $t<\tau^{(n)}_U\}$ have probability $1$, therefore so does their intersection $E$. But $\tau^{(n)}_U \uparrow \tau_U$ as $n \to \infty$, so it follows that $E$ is the event that Ito's formula for $f(X_t)$ holds when $t<\tau_U$.  $\Box$

Note that Ito's formula itself is a justification that $f(X)$ has a semimartingale decomposition, but which is valid only for times $t<\tau_U$ in this case.

Comment: Well, ultimately i still feel that you end in the same problem. The stochastic integral is also , atleast to the extend of my knowledge, defined as a $[0,\infty)$ process.  But i understand it in the sense that you can define a stochastic integral for $t<\tau_U$ as say $\int_0^t H_sdB_s=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1_{[\tau^{(k-1)},\tau^{(k)}]}(t)\int H^{\tau^{(k)}}_s dB_s$. But then you have to prove that it satisfies all the properties that a normal stochastic integral satisfies?


Also, how does it make sense to talk about a semimartingale decomposition that is only valid for times $t<\tau$

Comment: Personally the way I would interpret the statement "$X_t=\int_0^tH_s dB_s$ is valid for $t<\tau$" is that the Riemann sums $X^{(n)}_t$ associated to $\int_0^tH_s dB_s$ converge in probability to $X_t$ on the event $t<\tau$, in the sense that for each $t\geq 0$, we have $P(|X_t^{(n)}-X_t|>\epsilon,\;t<\tau) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Also, you are correct to question my statement that a semimartingale decomposition can be valid for $t<\tau$, as that doesn't mean anything formally. What I basically meant was that there exists a sequence $\tau_n$ of stopping times converging up to $\tau$ for which a semimartingale decomposition $X^{\tau_n}=M^n+A^n$ is valid for all $n$, and moreover $M^n_t,A^n_t$ agree with $M^{n+1}_t,A^{n+1}_t$ (respectively) for $t\leq \tau_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I resubmitted the comments a bunch of times because I needed to edit them beyond 5 minutes. But now they should make some sense I hope.